# How can I share a directory between containers in Kubernetes that originates from a container?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a directory within container A that I would like to share with container B.

For example I have a directory `/dataabc` on container A.

I've tried using a shared `hostPath` volume, however as this is empty when mounted - it makes the existing files non accessible. (`/dataabc` would be mounted on top of the existing `/dataabc/` from container A.

I could copy the files over on container startup - but this requires modification to the container. Is there a more simple way that does not require modification to the container?

Comment: This issue is also discussed here: http://blog.reactiveops.com/kubernetes-emptydir-not-the-same-as-dockers-volumes-from

Comment: You could do the copy in an init container. Mount the ``hostPath`` on ``/mnt`` in init container and copy into to. Then mount in desired location in main containers.

Comment: Hmm so I'd need to create an init image from my initial image in order to have the files? Sounds like a solution none the less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to @graham, I could reuse the existing container with just this minor modification to the pod config:

```
  initContainers:
  - args:
    - cp -r /var/www / && ls -altr /www/
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    image: example
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: example-init
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /www
      name: webroot
```